Invite to someone's Google Analytics Account
I received an email invite to look at someone's Google Analytics account to check if there is tracking. Here is the email:

But for some reason, when I click the link, it just takes me to my own Google Analytics account. And I don't see that person's account anywhere. Is there some steps I need to take to see that person's account?

It turns out I actually needed to obtain the user's credentials and add their account before the google invite could actually take me to their account.
